# Progress-bar not shown?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-progressbar

I used one [progress spinner library](https://github.com/anupamdhanuka/AndroidProgressHUD) from here. It was working fine when I use instance using params `AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>` It works perfect and shows Progress spinner  on UI.

I just modified it as I need JSONArray as a output so I modified it to `AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray>`

It stops to show Progres spinner. So I tried dummy  `publishProgress((Integer) ((i / count) * 100));` It calls method `onProgressUpdate` but progress spinner not shown.

```
 AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> asynTask = new GetEmployeeDetails(MainActivity.this).execute("");
        try {
          response = asynTask.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Resultz >>>>>>",response.toString());
      }
```

And implemented as

```
public class GetEmployeeDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray>
implements OnCancelListener {
  ProgressHUD mProgressHUD;
  private int statusCode = 0;
  private Activity activity;

  public GetEmployeeDetails(MainActivity activity) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    mProgressHUD = ProgressHUD.show(activity, "Posting Data...", true, false,
        this);
    super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
    JSONArray resultJSONArray = null;
    try {
      resultJSONArray = getData(params[0]);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultJSONArray;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
    // pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mProgressHUD.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    showHTTPResponseMessage(statusCode);
  }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    mProgressHUD.setMessage("Wait");
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
  }

  public JSONArray getData(String valueIWantToSend) throws JSONException,
  ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException {

    URI url = new URI("http://10.10.9.101:9393/users");
    String result = "";

    int count = 20;
    long totalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        publishProgress((Integer) ((i / count) * 100));
        // Escape early if cancel() is called
        if (isCancelled()) break;
    }

    // create HttpClient
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // make GET request to the given URL
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

    // receive response as inputStream
    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

    // convert inputstream to string
    if (inputStream != null) {
      result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
      Log.i("Result >>>>> ", result);
    } else
      result = "Did not work!";

    StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
    statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    Log.e("TAG", "HTTP Status Code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
    JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(result.toString());
    return jsonObject;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
    this.cancel(true);
    mProgressHUD.dismiss();
  }

  public void showHTTPResponseMessage(int messageCode) {
    if (messageCode == 200) {
      Toast.makeText(activity, "200 OOK Post Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
    }
    if (messageCode == 404) {
      Toast.makeText(activity, "404 Not Found. Check your posting server url",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (messageCode == 500) {
      Toast.makeText(activity,
          "500 Internal Server Error. Sorry We will back Soon!!",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (messageCode == 0)
      Toast.makeText(activity, "WOOOOOOFFFF... Unknonwn error",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
      throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
      result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

  }

}
```

Every thing working fine except the spinner not shown, Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `response = asynTask.get();`. Because it is still waiting for response, So window can't be attached.

Instead of using get() you can call another method in onPostExecute() which is responsible to perform your operations based on response.

Comment: I have created one method in MainActivity and called it in doInBackground. which stores my JSON response in MainActivity but is it feasible solution?